# Установка 1С. Не выполняется msiexec

Tags: cmd, 1с, powershell, windows-server

Требуется обновить платформу 1С на предприятии, написал скрипт, который включает в себя следующий фрагмент, но он не отрабатывает.

msiexec /i "path\1CEnterprise 8 (x86-64).msi" TRANSFORMS=adminstallrestart.mst, 1049.mst
DESIGNERALLCLIENTS=1 THICKCLIENT=0 THINCLIENTFILE=0 THINCLIENT=0 WEBSERVEREXT=0 SERVER=0 CONFREPOSSERVER=0 CONVERTER77=0 SERVERCLIENT=1 LANGUAGES=RU

Не запускается установка пакета на компьютере.
Что я проверил:

1. Доступ к шаре сервер имеет;
2. На сервере запускается процесс "Установщик Windows", но установка не происходит;

Не ошибок, ни уведомлений - ничего нет.

Setup.exe прекрасно запускает, но не хочется создавать юзерский mst, да и выяснить надо, в чем причина такого поведения.

Comment: А где собственно `/q? `adminstallrestart.mst` - там же на самом деле - полный путь до файла? А вообще, фундаментально - или смотри в сторону AD/GPO или в сторону Ansible. То, что ты делаешь - вполне укладывается в эти инструменты.